Is it possible to update PR label, after N number of approves in Github actions?
I want to automate logic of labels in my repo.
I tried to use https://github.com/actions/labeler, but it's only handle label regarding to file routes/branch names.
Is it possible to add label x when we have y approves on PR

It is possible through the Github API, now you may need to create a customizable workflow to achieve what you want through scripts or bash commands.

You can build a workflow using action/github-script@v6 for basic use-case. See this example. Since you want to run this workflow on every pr and assuming that each pr must have approval from 2 reviewer's, your workflow would look somthing like this:-
on:
  pull_request_review:
    types: [submitted]

jobs:
  label-on-approval:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Check for approvals
        id: check-approvals
        run: |
          PR_NUMBER=${{ github.event.pull_request.number }}
          OWNER=${{ github.repository_owner }}
          REPO=${{ github.event.repository.name }}
          TOKEN=${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}

          # Fetch reviews using curl
          REVIEWS=$(curl -s -H "Accept: application/vnd.github+json" \
                        -H "Authorization: Bearer $TOKEN" \
                        https://api.github.com/repos/$OWNER/$REPO/pulls/$PR_NUMBER/reviews)

          # Count the number of approvals
          APPROVALS=$(echo "$REVIEWS" | jq '[.[] | select(.state == "APPROVED")] | length')

          echo "Number of approvals: $APPROVALS"
          echo "::set-output name=approvals::$APPROVALS"

      - name: Add label if approvals meet threshold
        if: steps.check-approvals.outputs.approvals >= 2  # Change the threshold here
        run: |
          PR_NUMBER=${{ github.event.pull_request.number }}
          OWNER=${{ github.repository_owner }}
          REPO=${{ github.event.repository.name }}
          TOKEN=${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}

          # Add the label
          curl -s -X POST -H "Accept: application/vnd.github+json" \
               -H "Authorization: Bearer $TOKEN" \
               -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
               -d '{"labels":["x"]}' \
               https://api.github.com/repos/$OWNER/$REPO/issues/$PR_NUMBER/labels

